# Angularjs reset form with $touched input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to reset the form before I click outside input. But before resetting data, an error message flashes. Any idea how to do it without flashes?

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hOBZ3vAjBhFNEzq1EReF?p=preview

HTML:

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
 <form name="myForm" novalidate ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <input type="text" name="field" ng-minlength="8" ng-model="field">
   <span ng-if="myForm.field.$invalid && myForm.field.$touched" style="color: red">Error</span>
   <br>
   <a href="" ng-click="reset()">Reset</a>
 </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);  

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){

   $scope.reset = function(){
       $scope.field = "";
   }
});
```

Comment: If I understand your question, what you want is not compatible with keeping $touched. Try removing it.

Comment: Do you want that when you click the reset, never appear the error message?

Comment: Yes, when I type something and I click reset, error message should not appear

Comment: @jackuss you could try the way I suggested..by updating `ng-model` value lazily..

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ng-model-options` for this special case where you can update actual ng-model value after particular set of interval

```
  <input type="text" name="field" ng-minlength="8" ng-model="field" 
    ng-model-options="{ debounce: { 'default': 500, 'blur': 200 } }"/>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/rrf27gLeb9ZQoV78Ewh6?p=preview)